# Cloud service recommendation for pdf storage

Tags: mongodb, pdf, cloud

I'm creating a web app that will contain a lot of pdfs for educational notes.What i have figured is that these pdfs should not be stored in my database i.e mongodb so can anyone recommend a cloud service which is free or cheap that can be used to store a large amount of pdfs for my web application.Considering storage upto 50-60gb. Also, i'm using node and express for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Amazon Web Services S3 Bucket on there Free tier for up to 5GB. Otherwise try Cloud Front:

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

"As part of the AWS Free Usage Tier, you can get started with Amazon CloudFront for free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive 50 GB Data Transfer Out and 2,000,000 HTTP and HTTPS Requests each month for one year"